# Откуда было запущено приложение Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Как узнать приложение на **Laravel** было запущено из консоли или через броузер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Проверить запущено ли приложение из консоли можно `app()->runningInConsole()`.
- Запущено тестом: `app()->runningUnitTests()`

Реализация в [Laravel 8](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6bc7d1b250ad101e02ae93b7bdd1a0bc489646b7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L600):

```php
public function runningInConsole()
{
  if ($this->isRunningInConsole === null) {
    $this->isRunningInConsole = Env::get('APP_RUNNING_IN_CONSOLE') ?? (\PHP_SAPI === 'cli' || \PHP_SAPI === 'phpdbg');
  }

  return $this->runningUnitTests;
}

/**
 * Determine if the application is running unit tests.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function runningUnitTests()
{
  return $this['env'] === 'testing';
}
```